# Error in Ops.factor(host_neighbourhood, neighbourhood) : level sets of factors are different

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to compare the two values within variable columns to see how many are matched up and how many are different. However, it sent me this error and I am not sure where to fix the problem.

I used the pipe function and tried filtering function both inside and outside of `filter()` but it doesn't seem to matter.

```
same_nbh <- seattle_airbnb %>% filter(host_neighbourhood == neighbourhood)
```

I receive this error:

> Error in Ops.factor(host_neighbourhood, neighbourhood) : level sets of factors are different

Answer (score 0):

From `?factor`:

> a factor can only be compared to another factor with an identical set of levels (not
>        necessarily in the same ordering) or to a character vector.

So you need to convert the variables back to character (or stop them being turned into factors in the first place), e.g.

```
(seattle_airbnb 
   %>% mutate_at(c("host_neighbourhood","neighbourhood"), as.character)
   %>% filter(host_neighbourhood == neighbourhood)
)
```